# java threadlocal singleton - what is it?

Tags: java, jsf, thread-local, facescontext

In layman speak, what does it mean when somebody says an object is a threadlocal singleton in Java? I was at a lecture about Java Server Faces, and everytime the FacesContext was spoken of - the instructor always reminded us that it is a threadlocal singleton.

Answer (score 14):

There is only one unique instance of the [`FacesContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) per thread.

The [`FacesServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html) creates a [`ThreadLocal<FacesContext>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) on the beginning of the HTTP servlet request and removes it on the end of the HTTP servlet response associated with the HTTP servlet request. Whenever you do a [`FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentInstance%28%29) in your JSF code, you'll always get the one and the same instance throughout the entire HTTP servlet request/response processing.

Since HTTP servlet requests are executed by distinct threads and the `FacesContext` instance is attached as thread local variable to a single thread, no two HTTP servlet requests share the *same* `FacesContext` instance.