# How this works, keeping static (global) reference to the request data

Tags: java, jsf

I need to know how this works:

```
HttpServletRequest request =  (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

This means that, some where when the server receive the request (actually the Faces APIs who do that) , it did something like:

```
FacesContext fx = new FacesContext();
fx.setRequest(httpServletRequest);
FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(fx);
```

so.. suppose this scenario:

one request sent ... the FacesContext object populated .. and then it waits 5 seconds (by any mean, for example using `Thread.sleep()` ) in this while .. another request sent who - by my understanding- will override the contents of the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` object .. so when the previous request came from the sleep, it will read the overriden contents..

Is my understanding true???

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true. Every HTTP request/response cycle is executed in a single and fully dedicated thread. The `FacesContext` is created in the beginning of a request and stored as a [`ThreadLocal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable which is trashed when the response is finished. The `getCurrentInstance()` returns the `ThreadLocal` variable. Anywhere in the code which is executed in the same thread (read: the same request) will have access to the same `FacesContext` instance. Different requests run in *their own* threads with *their own* `FacesContext` instance. The creation and destroy of the `FacesContext` is managed by the `FacesServlet`.

#### See also:

- [java threadlocal singleton - what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137860/java-threadlocal-singleton-what-is-it) - related answer
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables) - explains servlet lifecycle
- [How to initialize an API in servlet environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753913/how-to-initialize-an-api-in-servlet-environment/5755367#5755367) - code example of how to implement `ThreadLocal`