# Lifecycle of FacesContext?

Tags: jsf-2, thread-safety, facescontext

While going through the [javadoc of `FacesContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html), I came across this sentence

> The instance remains active until its release() method is called, after which no further references to this instance are allowed. While a FacesContext instance is active, it must not be referenced from any thread other than the one upon which the servlet container executing this web application utilizes for the processing of this request

Does this mean that `FacesContext` will never go for garbage collection, and the instance will be destroyed only when the current-webapplication stops (server is stopped)?

Is `FacesContext` following singleton pattern? In that case, how will it behave when multiple request and coming for rendering response simultaneously as it serves only one request per time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Does this mean that `FacesContext` will never go for garbage collection, and the instance will be destroyed only when the current-webapplication stops (server is stopped)?*

No, you read it wrongly. The `FacesContext` lives as long as a single HTTP request. It will (actually, "can" is a better word) not immediately be GC'ed if you incorrectly reference it anywhere in **your own** code beyond its scope. E.g. as a property of a session scoped managed bean which lives longer than a single HTTP request:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BadSessionBean {

    // Bad Example! Never do this! Not threadsafe and instance can't be GC'ed by end of request!
    private FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

}
```

If you aren't doing that anywhere in your code, and thus you're *always* obtaining the current instance in method local scope, then it will have the chance to be properly GC'ed.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class GoodSessionBean {

    public void someMethod() {
        // OK! Declared in method local scope and thus threadsafe.
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

}
```

Please note that this GC behavior is not specific to JSF/`FacesContext`, it's just specific to basic Java in general.

---

> *Is `FacesContext` following singleton pattern? In that case, how will it behave when multiple request and coming for rendering response simultaneously as it serves only one request per time?*

No, it's definitely not a singleton. It's a [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) instance which is created by `FacesServlet` right after the `service()` method is entered and destroyed by the `FacesServlet` right before the `service()` method is left. Thus, there's only one instance **per request** (and thus not per application). Note that one HTTP request counts as one separate thread. There can be multiple threads (read: requests) and thus there can be multiple instances of the `FacesContext` during application's lifetime. Its main pattern is the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), but that's further not related to it being a `ThreadLocal`.

#### See also:

- [java threadlocal singleton - what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137860/java-threadlocal-singleton-what-is-it/5137881#5137881)
- [How to initialize an API in servlet environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753913/how-to-initialize-an-api-in-servlet-environment/5755367#5755367)
- [Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195)

Comment: Note that one HTTP request counts as one separate thread. There can be multiple threads (read: requests) and thus there can be multiple instances of the FacesContext during application's lifetime..Thanks for going in depth..I was looking for this sentence..:)

Comment: So in that case , it is not recommended to get an instance of FacesContext in a session scoped bean? As by rule the instance of FacesContext should not be shared between 2 Requests?

Comment: You're welcome. This related answer is in that case likely also helpful/enlightenend to understand better how servlets work under the covers of JSF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Comment: No, you read it wrong again. It's not recommended to assign it as a property of a session scoped bean. You must instead obtain it in method local scope. Any variables declared in method block are threadlocal (and thus thread safe). I extended the answer with another example.

Comment: Ok..ok..then it will be destroyed once we get out of the method..as there will be no reference..

Comment: Note that it's not the context instance itself which get destroyed, it's just the object reference which get destroyed. Now pieces comes together, I strongly recommend to take a JSF pause and take some time to learn the Java basics. GC and object references are also covered in a sane basic Java tutorial like Oracle's own one and the SCJP book.

Comment: I had bookmarked the link regarding your explanation on Servlets a long time ago..:)

Comment: Reading that answer, I had the impression that in a session scoped managed bean, I have different requests for each method. Is that right?